# How can i modify only the size and position for item selected from collectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

i have a collection view and when i select an item i want to make bigger that image and add a frame . I do this , but the rest of images are moving also . This is how i was doing :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
       selectedIndexPath = nil;
        [self.player stop];

        CollectionViewCell *cellOne =  [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cellOne.inner.hidden=YES;


        recipeImageView.frame=CGRectMake(recipeImageView.frame.origin.x, recipeImageView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100);
        recipeImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    }
    else {
        // select new cell
        celulaSelectata=indexPath;
        UICollectionViewCell  *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

        CollectionViewCell *cellOne =  [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        recipeImageView.frame=CGRectMake(recipeImageView.frame.origin.x, recipeImageView.frame.origin.y, 120, 120);
        cellOne.inner.frame=recipeImageView.frame;
```

How can i modify only the size and position for item selected ?

Answer (score 1):

`selectedIndexPath` create `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for selected cell and call `invalidateItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths` to update cell for selected `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`

Subclass your `UICollectionViewLayout` and add funtion in your `UICollectionViewLayout` and invalidate any `indexPath` to update

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndexPath]) {
        //set attributes
        //attribute.frame = //setframe;
    }
    return attribute;
}
```

Comment: can you gave an exemple please ?

Comment: layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath not found

Comment: subclass your `UICollectionViewLayout` the layout you are using for your `collectionView`

Comment: i solve this but when i select an item , the item and onether one appear like selected

Comment: then then after selecting new item invalidate previous one also. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
```

I think you have to write this part in the `cellforRow` method.

not in `didSelectRowAtIndexpath`.